# How to add rewrite rule to custom post type with parent in url with cpt ui?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create custom post types but i need the posts of custom post type to have the url along with parent category. Example for now i have custom post types science, tech, business. The url of each post is mysite.com/science/postname. what i need is mysite.com/articles/science/post name. I tried giving articles/science in rewrite rule of cpt ui but it gives 404 error. Can you guys point me to right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hierarchical must be set to true and make sure you have the Article post type set as the parent of the science post type

....and be sure to flush the permalinks after making changes

Comment: tqs but how to set articles as parent? i added articles post type as parent from parent field also set the the parent child relationship as true in article post type including hierarchy. I doubt if i have set it right.

Comment: Are you using the CPT UI plugin??